# Add text to file if not exist

Tags: batch-file

I'm successfully adding file content with this script,

```
@echo off

set hostspath=%windir%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

echo 99.127.158.114 www.example.com >> %hostspath%

exit
```

However, if I run the bat file again, it add the lines again. And there are duplicates. What I want to do this, when I run the bat, it should make the file content empty, and then put the content (or check if addedi and not add). What is the correct way to do that ?

Comment: This could be completely off base (I'm not a windows guy) but `>>` usually means **append**. Try using `>` instead which overwrites the file

Comment: @DrewHammond: you are right. But `hosts` usually has more than one line and he wants to add a line, if it isn't already there.

Comment: Where's `sed` when you need it?

Comment: @DrewHammond `Repl.bat` is sed for Windows.  This task just needs findstr if the aim is to check for the existing IP or URL.

Comment: @Stephan I'm not "he".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find "99.127.158.114 www.example.com" %hostspath% || echo 99.127.158.114 www.example.com>>%hostspath%
```

`||` acts as "if previous command failed, then..."